# Xml path with condition

Tags: xml, xpath

i have the follow Xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE inventory SYSTEM "books.dtd">
<inventory>
    <book num="b1">
        <title>Snow Crash</title>
        <author>Neal Stephenson</author>
        <publisher>Spectra</publisher>
        <price>14.95</price>
        <chapter>
            <title>Snow Crash - Chapter A</title>
            <paragraph>
                This is the <emph>first</emph> paragraph.
                <image file="firstParagraphImage.gif"/>
                afetr image...
            </paragraph>
            <paragraph>
                This is the <emph>second</emph> paragraph.
                <image file="secondParagraphImage.gif"/>
                afetr image...
            </paragraph>
        </chapter>
        <chapter>
            <title>Snow Crash - Chapter B</title>
            <section>
                <title>Chapter B - section 1</title>
                <paragraph>
                    This is the <emph>first</emph> paragraph of section 1 in chapter B.
                    <image file="Chapter_B_firstParagraphImage.gif"/>
                    afetr image...
                </paragraph>
                <paragraph>
                    This is the <emph>second</emph> paragraph of section 1 in chapter B.
                    <image file="Chapter_B_secondParagraphImage.gif"/>
                    afetr image...
                </paragraph>
            </section>
        </chapter>
        <chapter>
            <title>Chapter C</title>
            <paragraph>
                This chapter has no images and only one paragraph
            </paragraph>
        </chapter>
    </book>
    <book num="b2">
        <title>Burning Tower</title>
        <author>Larry Niven</author>
        <author>Jerry Pournelle</author>
        <publisher>Pocket</publisher>
        <price>5.99</price>
        <chapter>
            <title>Burning Tower - Chapter A</title>
        </chapter>
        <chapter>
            <title>Burning Tower - Chapter B</title>
            <paragraph>
                This is the <emph>second</emph> paragraph of chapter B in the 2nd book.
                <image file="Burning_Tower_Chapter_B_secondParagraphImage.gif"/>
                afetr image...
            </paragraph>
        </chapter>
    </book>
    <book num="b3">
        <title>Zodiac</title>
        <author>Neal Stephenson</author>
        <publisher>Spectra</publisher>
        <price>7.50</price>
        <chapter>
            <title>Zodiac - Chapter A</title>
        </chapter>
    </book>
    <!-- more books... -->
</inventory>
```

how to write the follow  XmlPath 1.0:

1)  return all the books provided all the book's prices  are not equal 14.95 ?

2)  return all the books that thier price is bigger then the  price of the book after them .

thank s in advance .

Comment: What language are you using?? Please provide more context, also add what you have tried to accomplish your objective. Don't just ask 'how do I do this' questions.

Comment: no language  , i only want to learn about  XmlPath 1.0 with that condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how to write the follow XmlPath 1.0:

1) return all the books provided all the book's prices are not equal 14.95 ?

```
/inventory/book[price/text() != 14.95]
```

"/inventory/book" gives you all the children elements named "books" of the "inventory" Node. and  "price/text() != 14.95" simply means for each book, check whether one their child element named "price" is different than 14.95. instead of "/inventory/book", you can rather use "//book" for the convenience of your application. "//book" ask for all descendant elements named "book" from your current node (in this case the root element)

2) return all the books that thier price is bigger then the price of the book after them .

```
/inventory/book[price >  following-sibling::book[position() = 1]/price]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try these:

> 1) return all the books provided all the book's prices are not equal 14.95 ?

```
 /inventory/book[price != 14.95]/title
```

> 2) return all the books that their price is bigger than the price of the book after them.

```
 /inventory/book[price>following-sibling::*[1]/price]/title
```